# Rails:как изменить путь к приложению на под-путь?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect

Есть приложение на ruby-on-rails, необходимо чтобы оно всё было доступно по пути `domain_name/subroute`

Изначально пробовала сделать редирект с помощью роутера: `domain_name/subroute` указывал на `root приложения`, но в этом случае все ссылки-пути приложения вели к `domain_name/...` a  не к `domain_name/subroute/...`

Как можно все приложение перенести в  sub route?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для нового Ruby on Rail работает такая схема: https://gist.github.com/shad1w/75e7ebbbdc5382719cd06f56bbe6acd0

> We will now modify our app to take into account the environment
>   variable MYAPP_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT.
>
> Routes
>
> All routes need to be wrapped in a scope, which defines the root path
>   to serve from:
>
> Rails.application.routes.draw do   scope
>   ENV['MYAPP_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT'] || '/' do
>       # Routes here   end end Fixing assets
>
> The change to the routes does not make any changes to the assets.
>   These would still be served relative to /.
>
> To change this, the following line needs to be added in
>   config/application.rb
>
> config.assets.prefix =
>   "#{ENV['MYAPP_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT']}#{config.assets.prefix}" Also make
>   sure that images are precompiled. For this, add the following to
>   config/initializers/assets.rb:
>
> Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w[*.png *.jpg *.jpeg
>   *.gif] Starting the app
>
> Before starting the app, the environment variable
>   MYAPP_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT should be set to whatever subdirectory the app
>   should be served from. On a linux server, this would be done by using
>   export MYAPP_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT='/myapp'
>
> If the app should be served from the root directory, this variable
>   doesn't need to be set at all.
>
> Now, the Rails server can be started.

Answer (score 0):

Необходимо указать путь в конфиге

```
config.relative_url_root = "/subroute"
```

или в переменной `RAILS_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT`

Вот тут в [рельсогайде](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#deploy-to-a-subdirectory-relative-url-root) подробнее об этом

Comment: Эта настройка работала только в старых версиях. В новых ее просто нет: выдает ошибку при попытке ее вставить.